# TypeError: has no method 'async'

Tags: intern

I'm trying to run the Async example and have the following code:

```
registerSuite({
    name: 'Test Dashboard empty after removing all projects and data',

    setup: function () {
        var dfd = this.async(1000);

        console.info('\n In setup');
        remote = this.remote;
        remote.setWindowSize(1024,768);
```

When I run this, I'm seeing the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Suite> has no method 'async'
  at Suite.registerSuite.setup  <tests/dashboard/dashboard_empty.js:18:28>
  at <Suite.target.(anonymous function).dispatcher [as setup] (/home/bkuhlman/internjs_func/Lopez-Internjs-Func/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/aspect.js:95:31)>
  at callOnSuite  <node_modules/intern/lib/Suite.js:157:42>
  at call  <node_modules/intern/lib/Suite.js:208:13>
  at Suite.run  <node_modules/intern/lib/Suite.js:306:4>
  at <node_modules/intern/lib/Suite.js:237:13>
  at signalListener  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:37:21>
  at Promise.then.promise.then  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/Deferred.js:258:5>
  at runTest  <node_modules/intern/lib/Suite.js:236:46>
  at <node_modules/intern/lib/Suite.js:249:7>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as the error describes. `setup` is a suite lifecycle method, not a test method, so it has no `this.async`. If you need to perform an asynchronous operation from a lifecycle method you will need to return a promise. This will be addressed in a future version of Intern.